# TypeScript: overriding a Map with callback function as value when its argument is of more specific type doesn't work (TS2416)

Tags: typescript

I have installed the newest version of TypeScript (4.2.4). Take this minimal example:

```js
class Vehicle {
  buildYear: number;
  weight: number;

  vehicleRegister: Map<string, (vehicle: Vehicle) => void>;
}

class Boat extends Vehicle {
  name: string;

  // boat register
  vehicleRegister: Map<string, (vehicle: Boat) => void>; // error
}
```

As you can see, I am extending the Vehicle class with the Boat class and overriding the `vehicleRegister`-property. However, doing it like this gives me the following error:

```
TS2416: Property 'vehicleRegister' in type 'Boat' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Vehicle'.   
  Type 'Map<string, (vehicle: Boat) => void>' is not assignable to type 'Map<string, (vehicle: Vehicle) => void>'.
    Type '(vehicle: Boat) => void' is not assignable to type '(vehicle: Vehicle) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'vehicle' and 'vehicle' are incompatible.         
        Property 'name' is missing in type 'Vehicle' but required in type 'Boat'.
```

I do not understand why I cannot substitute the type of a base class with the type of a more specific class in the function argument of the callback function? Maybe I got the LSP wrong, but shouldn't every call to a function `(vehicle: Boat) => void` also satisfy the contract established by the base type `(vehicle: Vehicle) => void`? I feel like I'm completely thinking this wrong. I'm especially confused since the following code works:

```js
class Vehicle {
  buildYear: number;
  weight: number;

  vehicleRepository: Vehicle[];
}

class Boat extends Vehicle {
  name: string;

  vehicleRepository: Boat[]; // works
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this has to do with function types being contravariant by their parameter types, meaning that having the more specific type in the parameter list does *not* mean that the function is a subtype of the function with the more general parameter type, but actually vice versa!

If anyone encounters the same issue, you can take a look here, for instance: https://dmitripavlutin.com/typescript-covariance-contravariance/